# ASP.NET on button click in user control set the value of a textbox in the main page using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

net/C# application, I have a user control containing a button.

I am loading the control in a PlaceHolder on the main page at runtime.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code Behind:

```
MyControl CC = (MyControl)LoadControl("Controls/MyControl.ascx");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(CC);
```

on the main page I have a text box and a link button. I want to do the following:

When the user clicks on the button in the user control, the textbox value is set to '5' and the link button click event is fired using javascript.

I tried the following but it did not work:

### IN THE MAIN PAGE:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PageBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonPage" runat="server" onclick="LinkButtonPage_Click" Text="Submit"></asp:LinkButton>
```

### IN THE USER CONTROL:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetPage(a) {
        var txtFld = document.getElementById("PageBox");
        txtFld.value = a;
        document.getElementById('LinkButtonPage').click();
        return false;
    }
</script>

<input type="button" id="Button1" onclick="SetPage('5');" value="Submit"/>
```

But when i click on the button nothig happens.

Thank you for any help

Comment: the ID in the client side is different than server side one. I edited my answer please check it.

Comment: by doing so I was getting an exception that the PageBox is not found. Thank you for your help, but I found another solution. It is in the answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the function directly in the onclick event of the button

```
<input type="button" id="Button1" onclick="document.getElementById('PageBox').value='5';document.getElementById('LinkButtonPage').click();return false;" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the ids of the controls wrong. You should be doing:

```
 document.getElementById('<%=PageBox.ClientID%>');
```

And

```
 document.getElementById('<%=LinkButtonPage.ClientID%>');
```

Also, you need to move your JavaScript function to the main page because that's the one that has the reference to both controls.

Comment: I did that but nothing is happening. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

if you want to submit the page after changing the textbox value try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetPage(a) {
        var txtFld = document.getElementById("<%=PageBox.ClientID%>");
        txtFld.value = a;
        document.forms[0].submit(); // or document.forms['formname'].submit()
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The textbox value is not changing.